# Editing a PDF with MuPDF in android

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using mupdf(1.0) to render PDFs in my android application but I also need to edit PDFs.
 it's not documented very well.
I am hoping to be able to edit PDFs using MuPDF rather than using another library.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

MuPDF isn't a PDF editor, currently you can;t use it to do editing, at least not without doing a lot of programming yourself. If you do want to extend MuPDF then you should firstly be aware that there is already some effort going on there.

If you are interested, I would suggest talking directly to the developers, they can be found on the #ghostscript IRC channel on irc.freenode.net